# Sum of range of numbers in an array(callback function)

Tags: javascript, arrays

What is wrong with this code?

```
function range(start, end){
  var arrayRange = [];
  for(i= start; i<=end; i++){
    arrayRange.push(i)
  }
  return(arrayRange);
}
var r = range(1,10);
console.log(r);

function sumRange(sumArray){
  var total = 0;

 for(var i=0; i <= sumArray.length; i++){
   total = total + sumArray[i];   
 }
  return total;
}

var s=sumRange(r);
console.log(s);
```

This is what gets displayed in console.

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
NaN
```

I'm trying an exercise from Eloquent Javascript to understand callback function. My aim is to produce this

```
console.log(sum(range(1,10)));
// 55
```

Comment: To start with, you need two separate functions `sum` and `range` to satisfy your aim. Currently you are defining `sumRange` as one in your code?

Comment: `var i=0; i < sumArray.length; i++`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is `i <= sumArray.length`, the array indexes are from 0 to `length -1` so the loop condition should be `i < sumArray.length`

In your case the last iteration of the loop will be `total + undefined` which will return `NaN`

```
function sumRange(sumArray) {
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < sumArray.length; i++) {
        total = total + sumArray[i];
    }
    return total;
}
```

---

You can use Array.reduce() like

```
function sumRange(sumArray) {
    return sumArray.reduce(function (sum, val) {
        return sum + val;
    }, 0);
}
```

Comment: Oh man! I feel silly. Arun, can you show me how to get this line working?

console.log(sum(range(1,10)));
to produce 55 in console

Answer (score 1):

In this part of the sum function:

```
for(var i=0; i <= sumArray.length; i++){
  total = total + sumArray[i];   
}
```

Because your condition is `i <= sumArray.length` instead of `i < sumArray.length`, you try to access an array index that has not been set. When you do this, JavaScript will yield `undefined` as the value, and `undefined` when added to any number, will produce `NaN`.

The `NaN` value is basically JavaScript's way of letting you know that something went wrong in the calculations, without actually being helpful enough to tell you *where* it went wrong. Even strict mode will not modify this behavior, so you just have to be careful when you work with arrays to avoid accessing undefined keys. By the way, the same behavior exists when you try to access undefined object keys (In JavaScript, arrays are just special cases of objects).

Recall that JavaScript's arrays are zero-indexed, i.e. an array with `n` elements will have index keys `0..n-1`, so you want to iterate *up to* the array's length non-inclusively using the condition

`i < sumArray.length`. As soon as this condition is false, you want to stop the iteration because you're in undefined territory.